# Variance of Binomial distribution proof using Binomial Theorem

Tags: self-study, variance, binomial-distribution

From [Proof 1](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Variance_of_Binomial_Distribution)

why is $\sum_{j=1}^{m}{m-1\choose j-1} p^{j-1}q^{(m-1)-(j-1)} = (p+q)^{m-1}$

shouldn't it be

$\sum_{j=1}^{m-1}{m-1\choose j-1} p^{j-1}q^{(m-1)-(j-1)} = (p+q)^{m-1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open up the first one, you have
$${n \choose 0}p^0q^{n}+...+{n\choose n}p^{n}q^0$$

where $n=m-1$. This is the same expansion written [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem). If you move $j$ upto $m-1$, instead of $m$, the $j-1$ term can be at most $m-2$, and you don't have the last term in the expansion.

Comment: I’m not sure I follow you exactly. Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: If you write the terms in your summation, there will be $m-1$ terms, but binomial expansion of $(x+y)^n$ has n+1 terms, which means binomial expansion of $(p+q)^{m-1}$ has $m$ terms.

Comment: @ ECII: $(p+q)^2=p^2+2pq+q^2$ has 3 terms, $(p+q)^3=p^3+3p^2q+3pq^2+q^3$ has 4 terms, ... in general $(p+q)^n$ has $(n+1)$ terms.